# Subtract 1 from all the following record key after deleting a specific one

Tags: cobol, gnucobol

i want to delete a specific item then subtract 1 from all the following item-id so it would look like something like this:

```
item-id item-name qty price
 [01]   Item 1     10   99
 [02]   Item 2     10   99
 [03]   Item 3     10   99
 [04]   Item 4     33   23
 [05]   Item 5     22   33
```

-Delete item-id 03
new output:

```
item-id item-name qty price
 [01]   Item 1     10   99
 [02]   Item 2     10   99
 [03]   Item 4     33   23
 [04]   Item 5     22   33
```

ive tried something like this the delete works correctly i just dont know how to subtract 1 from all the following item-id's

```
   ENVIRONMENT DIVISION.
   INPUT-OUTPUT SECTION.
   FILE-CONTROL.
   SELECT INVENTORY
   ASSIGN TO 'C:\Users\User\Desktop\FINALS\inventory.dat'
       ORGANIZATION IS INDEXED
       ACCESS MODE IS RANDOM
       RECORD KEY IS ITEM-ID.
   FILE SECTION.
     FD INVENTORY.
     01 FILE-INVENTORY.
        02 ITEM-ID PIC 9(2).
        02 ITEM-NAME PIC X(25).
        02 QTY PIC Z99.
        02 PRICE PIC ZZZ9.00.
   WORKING-STORAGE SECTION.
     01 WS-INVENTORY.
        02 WS-ID PIC 9(2).
        02 WS-GA PIC X(25).
        02 WS-QTY PIC 999.
        02 WS-PRC PIC 9999.00.
     01 WS-EOF PIC A(4).
   PROCEDURE DIVISION.
       DEL-ITEM.
       OPEN I-O INVENTORY
       DISPLAY "  ENTER ID OF THE PRODUCT YOU WANT TO DELETE"
       DISPLAY "  ITEM ID: " WITH NO ADVANCING
       ACCEPT ITEM-ID
       MOVE ITEM-ID TO WS-ID
       DELETE INVENTORY
       INVALID KEY
            DISPLAY "ITEM DOES NOT EXIST"
       END-DELETE
       MOVE WS-ID TO ITEM-ID
       READ INVENTORY NEXT INTO WS-INVENTORY
       NOT AT END PERFORM ID-CHECK UNTIL WS-EOF = 'TRUE'
       AT END MOVE 'TRUE' TO WS-EOF
       CLOSE INVENTORY
   ID-CHECK.
       SUBTRACT 1 FROM WS-ID GIVING ITEM-ID REWRITE FILE-INVENTORY.
```

Comment: When asking about file operations, please include the `SELECT` statement and `FD` (including enough of the `01` to identify key elements) for the file. Generally, include any data items from the `DATA DIVISION` referenced in the question.

Comment: `ACCESS MODE IS RANDOM` is not compatible with `READ INVENTORY NEXT`. There are other problems, as well. What error message(s) did you receive?

Comment: @RickSmith i have not received any error message from my compiler(Open Cobol IDE) and also this is just part of the program I wrote

Comment: As a regular function of an application this is a really bad idea. Leave the IDs alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using `DELETE` to remove a record, the `DELETE` statement must be preceded by a successful `READ` statement. For example,

```
    READ INVENTORY KEY ITEM-ID
    INVALID KEY
        SET some-error-condition TO TRUE
    NOT INVALID KEY
        DELETE INVENTORY
            more tests for errors
        END-DELETE
    END-READ
```

After successfully deleting the record, a loop is needed to change the prime record key of the remaining records.

Note that when changing the prime record key, `REWRITE` cannot be used. For `ACCESS MODE IS RANDOM`, use something like the following as a more complete example,

```
01 WS-DELETE-KEY PIC 99.
01 WS-DELETE-STATUS PIC 9 VALUE 0.
  88 RECORD-NOT-FOUND VALUE 1.
  88 RECORD-DELETED VALUE 2.
  88 DELETE-FAILED VALUE 3.
  88 NO-MORE-RECORDS VALUE 4.

    ACCEPT WS-DELETE-KEY
    PERFORM DELETE-RECORD
    IF RECORD-DELETED
        ADD 1 TO WS-DELETE-KEY
        PERFORM CHANGE-PRIMARY-KEY *> for the remaining records
            VARYING WS-DELETE-KEY FROM WS-DELETE-KEY BY 1
            UNTIL NO-MORE-RECORDS
        END-PERFORM
    END-IF
    .

DELETE-RECORD.
    MOVE WS-DELETE-KEY TO ITEM-ID
    READ INVENTORY KEY ITEM-ID
    INVALID KEY
        SET RECORD-NOT-FOUND TO TRUE
    NOT INVALID KEY
        DELETE INVENTORY
        INVALID KEY
            SET DELETE-FAILED TO TRUE
        NOT INVALID KEY
            SET RECORD-DELETED TO TRUE
        END-DELETE
    END-READ
    .

CHANGE-PRIMARY-KEY.
    MOVE WS-DELETE-KEY TO ITEM-ID
    READ INVENTORY KEY ITEM-ID
    INVALID KEY
        SET NO-MORE-RECORDS TO TRUE
    NOT INVALID KEY
        DELETE INVENTORY
        SUBTRACT 1 FROM ITEM-ID
        WRITE FILE-INVENTORY
    END-READ
```

This assumes that all remaining records are sequentially numbered and that the failure to read a record means there are no more records.

It may be wise to add additional checks in `CHANGE-PRIMARY-KEY` for other errors after the `DELETE` and `WRITE` statements.

For `ACCESS MODE IS DYNAMIC` the code is similar but could use `START` and `READ ... NEXT` statements.

Comment: Thanks for this, though rewrite somehow works even when I'm using RANDOM ACCESS MODE, as long as the one I'm rewriting is not a record key.

Answer (score 0):

You probably shouldn't be doing this. It's almost always a bad idea to change a primary key, because it can result in undefined behavior, i.e. you could mess up any other programs that use that file, especially if they have it open concurrently. It also could create a race condition. To be totally safe, kill all other running processes that could be potentially accessing the file using OS SYSTEM calls, open the input file with a lock, open an output file, re-write the file with the new keys under a different name (skipping that record of course),  close the output file, close the input file, delete the input file, then rename the output file to the original name. Then you can restart any processes that use it.

A primary key isn't meant to be a meaningful data value, if it is, it is a "smell" that perhaps you should rethink your schema design. If your goal is to read an index file sequentially, then open it with ACCESS IS SEQUENTIAL and READ NEXT RECORD. That way it won't matter what the explicit key values are, or if there are gaps. if you are reading it later with ACCESS IS RANDOM, just include an INVALID KEY clause in your read to handle the missing key. What if there is another index file that has the deleted record key saved in a field as a foreign key? If so, you have just created an orphan and blown your referential integrity.

As a matter of fact, before doing this, you need to know for sure that this is not the case, otherwise, you should delete any other index file records that reference this one as a cascade, or check any other files that might have this key as a foreign key,  and not allow the delete if they do, assuming you are in full control of the schema.  Cheers!